# Styling django non-field errors on forms

Tags: django, django-forms, styling

If I look in Django's *forms.py*, `as_p()` calls `_html_output()`, which styles field errors with `self.error_class()` (although I can't locate the definition of that).

However, `_html_output()` does NOT style `non_field_errors` (a.k.a. top_errors in the code).

How does one style the non-field errors?  Cut and paste all of _html_output?

I am using Django 1.0.

Answer (score 29):

I use this template to style non fields errors:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
  <div class="non-field-errors">
    {% for err in form.non_field_errors %}
      <p class="form-error">{{ err }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 10):

In your template you can access {{ form.non_field_errors }} and render them however you like.  Here's how the Django admin handles them for example: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html#L40

Comment: Thanks.  Sad to recreate all the form rendering code in template language, but maybe that is the right thing. Do you know of a ref to the full template equivalent of as_p?  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields is close, but probably not the same.

Answer (score 9):

**Options:**

Both `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` and `{{ form.non_field_errors.as_ul }}` do the same thing.

`{{ form.non_field_errors.as_text }}` displays the errors with an `*` in front of the text.

This article is also helpful in explaining why the `*` will not be removed [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4471)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without complicating the template language. In Django 3 the non_field_errors list has classes "errorlist nonfield", so you can simply use CSS to style them:

In your CSS file:

```
.errorlist.nonfield {
    color: red;
}
```

In your html template:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```